# Firebase Storage Image Not Showing

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

Firebase Storage Image not showing for 2/3 days. I have some published apps, inside those apps have some Images showing from Firebase Storage and now suddenly it is not showing/viewing. I have also checked those images from Browser > Firebase Console > Storage, but it is not showing image preview and shows: "**Error loading preview**". But My Firebase Firestore data is showing without any error. I checked Storage Quota, no issue about that. My Firebase Plan is "Blaze" Pay as you go.

*Now, what steps should I take to solve the problem? Can anybody help me regarding this issue?*

[image: Error loading preview]

Comment: Error Image Link https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHKQB.png

Comment: I just uploaded an image to one of my own projects through the Firebase console, and a preview shows without any problems in the Firebase console. I then set up a tiny test page [here](https://jsbin.com/purezib/edit?html,js,output) and also uploaded, downloaded and previewed an image without problems. Most likely your upload gets corrupted, but it's impossible to say more without seeing the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (in a similarly small format to the link I provided).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not firebase problem, i already contacted with firebase team.
This problem happening from 29th December from Bangladesh.
I think this is an mistake from BTCL, now you can use VPN but this is not solution,
We have to wait or have to communicated with BTCL for solve this issue.

Comment: Apparently, `storage.googleapis.com` isn't working in Bangladesh. This is also affecting Flutter's download/update since it's all hosted there.

Answer (score 1):

I even couldn't deploy firebase functions using firebase-tools from Bangladesh.
So I contacted firebase team and seems they have nothing to do as this is a country specific problem.
For now I am deploying functions from a headless remote environment.
This issue needs to be sort out either BTRC or google.