# Firebase Storage upload permissions issue using Admin SDK

Tags: google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Storage to keep a collection of images. Some of those images are uploaded from a client app using the Firebase JS SDK and the rest are uploaded from a backend server using the firebase-admin npm module. Both uploads work correctly but when I access the images from the Firebase console, the images uploaded using the firebase-admin sdk are not accessible:

**Upload from firebase**
[image: Upload from firebase]

**Upload from firebase-admin**
[image]

I understand this happens because I'm using the Service Account when uploading the file with the firebase-admin. Is there anyway I can automatically grant permissions to the **firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com** user on every file upload?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553413/firebase-storage-image-not-showing

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59532052/image-loading-and-uploading-to-firebase-storage-not-working-in-android-and-fireb